# Adding a frame border to a dataframe in Excel

Tags: pandas, formatting, xlsxwriter, styleframe

It seems simplistic as a task to perform, but I've been having hard time to add a border frame to my excel-written table (using xlsxwriter engine). The only way I could do so is by getting the size of my df & starting row/column then loop on each cell and format it, which is redundant. Is there a solution I'm not seeing ? I tried the styleframe module in vain.

Reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler, utils

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
df = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'center'})
writer = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter("Test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Random', index=False)

format_x = workbook.add_format({'border': 2})
worksheet.set_column('A:B',20,format_x)
writer.save()
```

Comment: styleframe only supports openpyxl. I can't check at the moment, but I'm pretty sure that trying to use xlsxwriter should raise an error.

Comment: Also, you are using pandas' styling that only works on the web. You are not using styleframe's styling at all. Please have a look at styleframe's docs.

Comment: Would formatting the dataframe as a table be a suitable workaround: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#adding-a-dataframe-to-a-worksheet-table Some of the table formats have distinct borders.